# SFML UDPSockets error sending

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, sfml

I am trying to send an extended packet using UDPSocket, and it seems that the send function is returning 4, which according to http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1UdpSocket.php means that "The TCP socket has been disconnected." I dont know what I have done, especially as I am using UDP sockets and not TCP.

```
packet << playerVariables;
    if (socket.send(packet, recipientAddress, recipientPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::printf("%d", socket.send(packet, recipientAddress, recipientPort));

    }
    else
    {
        std::printf("sent /n");
    }
```

and these are my extensions to the packet

```
sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const playerStruct& player)
{
    return packet << player.xPos << player.yPos << player.health;
}

sf::Packet& operator >>(sf::Packet& packet, playerStruct& player)
{
    return packet >> player.xPos >> player.yPos >> player.health;
```

Comment: I was being silly for the return number, it is saying error, as enums start at 0, but still need help :P